# install style-property in gtk3 of type enum

Tags: c, enums, properties, gtk3

I want to install a enum-style- property using [g_param_spec_enum](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Standard-Parameter-and-Value-Types.html#g-param-spec-enum):

```
  gtk_widget_class_install_style_property(gobject_class, g_param_spec_enum(
          "shadow-type",                //name
          "shadow-type",                //nick
          "type of shadow",             //blurb
          GtkShadowType,                //type
          GTK_SHADOW_NONE,              //default
          G_PARAM_READWRITE ));         //flags
```

However [GtkShadowType](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Standard-Enumerations.html#GtkShadowType) is not a GType, so it will not work this way:

```
thunar-statusbar.c:106:12: error: expected expression before ‘GtkShadowType’
            GtkShadowType,    //type
```

Any idea how I can get a GType out of GtkShadowType?

My current fix is, to just use `g_param_spec_int` instead:

```
  gtk_widget_class_install_style_property(gobject_class, g_param_spec_int (
          "shadow-type",                //name
          "shadow-type",                //nick
          "the type of the shadow",     //blurb
          GTK_SHADOW_NONE,              //min
          GTK_SHADOW_ETCHED_OUT,        //max
          GTK_SHADOW_NONE,              //default
          G_PARAM_READWRITE));         //flags
```

Seems to work, but is not the official way to deal with enums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gtk_shadow_type_get_type()` to retrieve the GType. (For better or for worse, the `_get_type()` methods usually do not show up in the API documentation.)

Comment: Uff ... ok, that was surprisingly easy, thanks :D   ... think I will ask the gtk3 people to add these methods to the doc